# Java - Erro SQL Atualizando todos os Usuários

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, window-builder

Bom dia,

Estou com o seguinte problema meu SQL de updateUsuario está atualizando todos como faço para que ele apenas atualize o Usuário que acessou?

```
public class Acessar {

public static Connection con = dao.ConectarDB.getConexao();

public static String doLogin(model.Acessar usuario) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet autenticacao = null;
    ResultSet grupo = null;
    sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";

    try {

        // Validar Usuário
        ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, usuario.getSenha());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        autenticacao = rs; 

        // Validar Grupo
        ps = null;
        sql = null;
        rs = null;
        sql = "select * from usuario where grupo=?";

        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            ps.setString(1, "Suporte");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            grupo = rs;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }

        // Resultado da Autenticação
        if(autenticacao.next()) {

            // Autenticado!

            // Resultado do Grupo
            if(grupo.next()) {

            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return "lider";

        } else {
            return "erro";
        }            

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "erro";
    }

}

// (Corrigir) Está atualizando todos os Usuários!
public void atualizarUsuario(model.Acessar acesso) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "update usuario set acesso=?";

    // Inserção
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1, new Date(acesso.getAcesso().getTime()));
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na sua string SQL você precisa especificar qual usuário você deseja atualizar utilizando a clausula *where* para isso. Além disso, você precisa passar esse usuário como parametro em seu método **atualizarUsuario**.

Algo assim:

```
public void atualizarUsuario(model.Acessar acesso, Usuario usuario) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "update usuario set acesso=? where nome=?";

    // Inserção
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1, new Date(acesso.getAcesso().getTime()));
        ps.setString(2, usuario.getNome());
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Não conheço o seu modelo, por isso estou atualizando o usuário baseado no nome (assim como vc faz o login), mas isso, obviamente, pode implicar em problemas, quando dois usuários tiverem o mesmo nome.